# How to make a smooth image rotation animation programmatically?

Tags: android, animation

I want to rotate an image smoothly (no small stop at each cycle of rotate) without the use of xml code animation.

Like `linear_interpolator` at xml animation.

This is my code for rotate:

```
    RotateAnimation animRotate;
    AnimationSet animSet;

    animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
    animSet.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
    animSet.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.setFillEnabled(true);

    final RotateAnimation animRotate = new RotateAnimation(0.0f,360.0f,
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
        RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    animRotate.setDuration(10000);
    animRotate.setFillAfter(true);
    animSet.addAnimation(animRotate);
    animSet.setRepeatCount(-1);
    img.startAnimation(animRotate); 

    //at timer
    if (animRotate.hasEnded()) {
    img.startAnimation(animRotate);
    }
```

Comment: what is wrong with the code above?

Comment: 2nd try: does this code rotate already, but it isn'T rotating smooth enough?

Comment: edit code, see againt. 
In each cycle There is a Stop and again start. I do not want this interrupt

Comment: rotate to 359 Degrees not 360

Comment: Hey ! did you find the solution 3 years after ? I have the same issue